# HafTarah and Novi

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzibur-community, haftarah

It is preferable to *lein* the *HafTarah* from a *Novi*. Even a printed *Novi* is usable when it contains the entire sefer. The particular HafTarah printed in the Chumashim is not preferred. If the *Shul* does use a *Novi* for the *HafTarah*, each individual should read the *HafTarah* to himself along with the *ba’al maftir*. When the *HafTarah* is read from a *Novi* others should not read along out loud. Is there a source for this?

Comment: Do you have a source for any of these ideas?

Comment: Start using the [tag:sources-mekorot] tag for these questions

Comment: Where did you learn these are preferable? Have you seen people takie care to do it that way? This (& many of your questions) asserts things as true & then asks for a source, but we don't have any basis for the assertions being true right now. I could ask "it is preferable to put a napkin on one's head before lighting candles; source?" because that's how I saw someone cover her hair when I was a kid, but that doesn't make napkins preferred (and for that matter doesn't even make hair-covering at home preferred -- it's just one observation). Please show us why you ask, & don't assume/assert, ok?

Answer (score 2):

SA OC 284, MB quotes L'vush who wonders why a complete Navi is not used. Taz and Magen Avrohom hold that even printed on paper and not rolled is good. Magen Avrohom and Eiliya Rabba say that even so a complete Navi is required, and not what is included in the chumash.

MB continues: if a printed Navi is not available, there is to be lenient in order not to lose Haftorah reading. He then says that it is appropriate and proper for every shul to have a Navi written on Klaf (k'din).

Sha'ar Hatziyun 4 metions that it is expensive and so we cannot protest a shul that is lenient. However, in shuls where much money is spent on ornamentation, certainly they have a mitvah to purchase a complete Navi.

[From Dirshu note 2]
Chazon Ish OC 60:11 writes there is no difference between a complete Navi (printed) and the Chumash.

As to those Klaf that have all the Haftoros on them, Aruch Hashulchan 66 writes that some places in Lithuania has the custom. Rabbi S"Z Auerbach in Shulchan Shlomo s'if katan 1, writes that if a congregation does not have a complete Navi on klaf, the Haftoros klaf is better than a chumash.

"If the Shul does use a Novi for the HafTarah, each individual should read the HafTarah to himself along with the ba’al maftir."

I do not know a source for this. I would even question it because of the rule that two voices are not heard. On a personal note, i find it *very* annoying.

Comment: @Baruch - In many Hassidishe shteiblach that I have attended, everyone reads the Haftarah to himself quietly. Perahps, this is the reason? I agree that having everyone read aloud together with the Ba'al Kri'ah is annoying. However, for those that cannot read Hebrew well and / or don't know the trope, they miss out on the Haftarah altogether.

Comment: Perhaps what is the reason? How do they miss out? Sorry, i do not understand. I would like to know the source though, assuming there is one.

Comment: "Miss out" - meaning that someone who doesn't understand Hebrew or can't read trope, won't hear the Haftarah. I don't know how the custom of having each person read to himself originated.

Comment: Why does not understanding Hebrew or trope preclude *listening*?

Comment: Perhaps, you missed the point. Everyone, including the B'al Kri'ah and everyone in the congregation is reciting silently.

Comment: I did not realize that "everyone" included the Korei.  If that is the case, it is not being read b'tzibur and noone would be yotzei.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15736/discussion-between-danf-and-boruch-tkatch).